# Error unexpected token: "" (column 1, codepoint U+0000) when making file changes with a code editor

Tags: phpstorm, apache-phoenix, laravel-elixir

Whenever I make a change to a file using Atom or PhpStorm, I'm getting the following error:

> unexpected token: "" (column 1, codepoint U+0000)

However, if I use VIM, it works fine. What's going on? I've used PhpStorm when writing Elixir in the past and haven't had any issues. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and PhpStorm. 2018.2

Comment: Does this happens in specific file only .. or in any file? Does it happen with newly created files? Can you provide such file (share whole file, not copy-paste content)?

Comment: It's any file. For example, if I edit the dev.exs config file, or the router.ex file. It appears that no matter what edit I make, I get the error, almost as if my IDE is inserting hidden characters that elixir doesn't like.

Comment: No solid idea. At first I thought it might be indeed a hidden character somewhere (there is plugin that can show warn about it -- "zero width ...") .. but if it's in every file... 1) Check idea.log for possible hints (maybe some related exceptions etc) 2) Ensure that ALL active plugins are up-to-date 3) Disable all custom (not bundled by default) plugins and see if it make any difference. P.S. Since this happens even with Atom editor.. it might be something else (no idea what though)

Comment: try to delete project's `/.idea` folder and check if the problem occurs after that

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620186/mix-exs-file-changes-syntaxerror-mix-exs65-unexpected-token-column-1

Comment: I am modifying the tag since I don't believe you're discussing the Elixir langauge but instead the Elixir PHP package.

Comment: I would open the file with an hexadecimal editor (here's an [online one](https://hexed.it)) and check if it's really a [NULL character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm). It can be part of a [UTF-32 byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding) but I'd expect Atom and PhpStorm to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to a Ubuntu 18.04 box in Vagrant and the issue no longer occurs.

Comment: Can confirm that switching my VirtualBox vm to `ubuntu/bionic64` has fixed the issue - now I can edit Elixir files on Mac and successfully compile/build Elixir project using official Elixir Docker container inside Ubuntu 18.04 vm.